# Rendering issue of WPF app in Windows 7 OS and WIndows 8 OS

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

The following XAML:

```
<ProgressBar Height="10" BorderBrush="#898989" BorderThickness="2" 
             Foreground="#f1592a" Background="#363636" Margin="15,0" 
             VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" />
```

...generates the following styles:

[image]

How can I solve this difference in rendering?

I tried to make progress bar in 2 styles one with styling from Resource and one with inline style , BUt still getting the same behaviour . Here is the xaml i used and output

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="ProgressStyleMy" TargetType="ProgressBar">

        <Setter Property="BorderBrush"  Value="#898989" ></Setter>

        <Setter Property="BorderThickness"  Value="2" ></Setter>

        <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="#f1592a" ></Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background"  Value="#363636" ></Setter>

    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <StackPanel Background="Green">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Margin="10" Click="Button_Click">Start</Button>
            <Button Margin="10" Click="Button_Click_1">Start2</Button>
        </StackPanel>


        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Height="10"  BorderBrush="#898989" BorderThickness="2" Foreground="#f1592a" Background="#363636"  Name="pgsbar"
                                            Margin="15,10" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
        </ProgressBar>

        <ProgressBar Value="{Binding Progress}" Height="10"  Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=ProgressStyleMy}" Name="pgsbar2"
                                            Margin="15,10"  >
        </ProgressBar>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

[image]

Comment: Your image and title refer to Windows 7, yet your text within the question mentions Windows 8 & 8.1.  Could you confirm that you're getting different renderings in Windows 7 and Windows 8?

Answer (score 2):

What you're referring to is the Windows look and feel.  The top image demonstrates the default styling (Chrome) that is provided by the Windows 7, while the bottom one (Metro) has to do with Windows 8.  If you want to achieve Metro look in Windows 7, you'll have to edit the control template.

If you don't mind third-party resources, there is an excellent collection of Metro-styled controls over at http://mahapps.com/.  Here's the GitHub link: https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro  I figure it's better than trying to do it yourself, since someone else has done it already.

Here's the list of all of the controls available in the toolkit: http://mahapps.com/controls/

Click on the desired ones to see previews and how to get them working in your application.

Comment: Edit the control template means i have use reference like 
Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=customStyle}" ? Or something different?

Comment: @JMat Yes.  It's easy to accomplish using `Blend`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908(v=expression.40).aspx

Comment: @JMat Check my edit for a third-party toolkit to help you out.  It's open source.

Comment: I cant use metro styles since in my application i have to use set of specific custom styles . I tried your suggestions [Edit the control template ] no change in output . I editted my question and output is attached in Question

Comment: @JMat You have to change more than simply a style, you have to change things within the template: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294908(v=expression.40).aspx

Comment: Means i have to edit builtin template of ProgressBar control completely ?

Comment: @Jmat Yes, you have to edit its template.  It's not very hard... just follow the link.

Comment: @B.K. You may dump the template in the vs GUI to, bu selecting an item in the designer and rightclick it.